# Weird m "placeholder" card

Tags: magic-the-gathering

A while ago a friend of mine pulled an interesting card in a pack of Urza's Legacy. The back was normal, but the front was solid black with a white M on it. I can't find the card right now, but I made an image of roughly what it looked like.

I think at the time I was told it was a placeholder for when there was extra room on the cutting sheet, and was accidentally included in the pack. I cannot remember which rarity slot it occupied.

I am trying to find out **how much it is worth, or if there is any information about it online?** Googling "magic m placeholder" and variants of that are not turning up anything useful.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This appears to be called a "filler" card, and that word seems to be key to successful Googling.

See here for more info, entry 031 is the one you posted.

http://www.magiclibrarities.net/348-rarities-filler-cards-english-cards-index.html

Seems to be pretty rare.

Comment: That's the one! It looks like ChannelFireball sells one for $450 http://store.channelfireball.com/catalog/magic_singles-promotional_cards-promos_miscellaneous/black_m_filler_card/92331 and ebay has one for $699 http://www.ebay.com/itm/Very-Rare-Magic-Error-Filler-Card-from-the-1996-Pro-Tour-Decks-/160987070747?pt=Trading_Card_Games_US&hash=item257b93c11b though I wonder who would actually pay that.

Comment: Hard core collectors of anything, revel in the odd minutia....